# Is there an office rule which allows ribbon button to always be enabled

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to get my ribbon button to always be enabled not just when the user is viewing a message but I can't find any combination to make it happen yet

```
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
```

It seems to need some rules to upload but i can't figure out what to specify here.

Comment: In all practicality, if you build a ribbon command to show up on a message, it will virtually always be enabled (there are few cases when it won't be), so you should be able to nail your scenario almost all the time.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, we are trying to build an add-on that would allow for sending messages using a proprietary platform, thus we want to essentially replace the Compose window with our own.  Is there any way to achieve something like this in O365?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook web based add-ins are in the context of a selected/particular item. You need to develop a COM add-in (for example, a VSTO based) if you want to get access to the rich UI extensibility and be able to enable and disable controls dynamically.

You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v%3Doffice.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v%3Doffice.12))